# Search in Large data set

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list of user:friends (50,000) and a list of event attendees (25,000 events and list of attendees for each event). I want to find top k friends with whom the user goes to the event. This needs to be done for each user.

I tried traversing lists but is computationally very expensive. I am also trying to do it by creating weighted graph.(Python)

Let me know if there is any other approach.

Comment: Why not dump the data into a database and then query it? This is what databases are for, and they are optimized for it.

Comment: ok. thank you. I will try it on sample data and see the performance

Comment: @Hyperboreus I'm not sure copying things to disk and re-reading them can be called optimisation or ever considered a way to speed up an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Python's collection objects (dictionaries, sets, and collections.Counter) make short work of this task:

```
from collections import Counter

def top_k_friends(friends, events, k=2):
    '''Given a dictionary users mapped to their set of friends
    and a dictionary of events mapped to a set of their attendees,
    find the top k friends with whom the user goes to the event.
    Do this for each user.

    '''
    for user, users_friends in friends.iteritems():
        c = Counter()
        for event, attendees in events.iteritems():
            if user in attendees:
                c.update(users_friends.intersection(attendees))
        print user, '-->', c.most_common(k)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    friends = {
        'robert' : {'mary', 'marty', 'maggie', 'john'},
        'paul' : {'marty', 'mary', 'amber', 'susan'}
    }

    events = {
        'derby': {'amber', 'mary', 'robert'},
        'pageant': {'maggie', 'paul', 'amber', 'marty', 'john'},
        'fireworks': {'susan', 'robert', 'marty', 'paul', 'robert'}
    }

    top_k_friends(friends, events)
```

Comment: Worst case complexity: O(users^3*events). Quite bad but on average the number of friends and attendees will be much lower than the total users.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do it either in a database (e.g. [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)), or for a pure-python, in-memory option, see [norman](https://readthedocs.org/projects/norman/).  Either way would be much faster than trying to implement this yourself with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this.

Im assuming friends of a user is relatively less, and the events attended by a particular user is also much lesser than total number of events.

So have a boolean vector of attended events for each friend of the user.

Doing a dot product and those that have max will be the friend who most likely resembles the user.

Again,.before you do this..you will have to filter some events to keep the size of your vectors manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give you a code sample if I better understood what your current data structures look like, but this sounds like a job for a pandas dataframe groupby (in case you don't feel like actually using a database as others have suggested).

Comment: I have two csv files. 1 -usr_frnds.csv which contains two columns:  user and friends.  user is the user's id and friends is a space-delimited list of the user's friends'.  2- event_attendees.csv  has the columns event_id, yes. event_id identifies the event. yes is space-delimited lists of user id's.  I am also looking into the pandas dataframe. thanks for the suggestion